# Set Analysis QlikView

Tags: qlikview

Tengo la siguiente función:

```
Count ( DISTINCT {<Connections-={'-'}>} SerialNumber)
```

Soy Nuevo en QlikView y no llego a comprender muy bien lo que esta haciendo exactamente. Es decir, te cuenta los distintos Connections, pero con los signos de mayor y menor que aparecen me pierdo por completo.

Answer (score 1):

Los caracteres “-=” quieren decir distinto, para tu ejemplo quieres que el conteo de “SerialNumber” sea distinto y además que el campo “Connections“ sea diferente del carácter “-”

Lo que va dentro de las comillas angulares, se llama ”Set Analisys” (Análisis de conjuntos), que en Qlikview, es la manera de reducir la información, dicho de otra manera es una manera de filtrar la información, para que de un universo de datos, el grafico solo muestre solo los datos que quieres analizar, recuerda que Qlikview es una herramienta de BI, que una de su principales funciones es la de analizar la información. 
Un ejemplo de Set Analisys básico es:

Año = {2020}

Donde “Año” es el nombre del campo de la tabla de datos y “2020” es el año escrito de manera directa. Lo que quiere decir que ese grafico mostrara simpre y en todo momento el año 2020 como año fijo.
Pero que va a pasar para el siguiente año, cuando abra ese grafico, lo tendrá que cambiar de manera manual, al siguiente año “2021”. La verdadera solución es que se año, cambie de manera dinámica.

Año = {“$( =Year(Today()) )”}

Con eso, el problema se resuelve, ese año cambiara de manera automática, respecto al calendario.
Y eso agregado a tu expresión quedaría así:

Count ({$< Connections -= {'-'},  Año = {“$( =Year(Today()) )”} >} DISTINCT SerialNumber)

El conteo del campo, “SerialNumber” de manera distinta, donde el campo "Connections" sea no sea '-' y que solo sean datos del año en curso.

Esto es para que tengas una idea del funcionamiento, pero te recomiendo profundizar mas en el uso del Set Analisys, ya que sus funciones son muy amplias.
Te dejo un link de referencia.

Saludos.

https://help.qlik.com/es-ES/qlikview/April2019/Subsystems/Client/Content/QV_QlikView/ChartFunctions/SetAnalysis/set-analysis-expressions.htm

Comment: Como nota al margen, estaria bueno aclararle ademas que hace ese set analisys, que es contar los serial numbers que no tienen un - en el campo connections

Comment: buenas paso mucho tiempo pero aqui tienes un buen ejemplo
https://qlikwithfriends.com/index.php/2019/10/10/using-advanced-set-analysis-operators-to-power-your-visualizations/